# Element-wise multiplication with Keras

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, mask

I have a RGB image of shape `(256,256,3)` and I have a weight mask of shape `(256,256)`. How do I perform the element-wise multiplication between them with Keras? (all channels share the same mask)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a `Reshape` so both tensors have the same number of dimensions, and a `Multiply` layer

```
mask = Reshape((256,256,1))(mask) 
out = Multiply()([image,mask])
```

If you have variable shapes, you can use a single `Lambda` layer like this:

```py
import keras.backend as K 

def multiply(x):
    image,mask = x
    mask = K.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1) #could be K.stack([mask]*3, axis=-1) too 
    return mask*image

out = Lambda(multiply)([image,mask])
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for reshape. It would be broadcasted, right?

Comment: Sometimes it is, I'm not really sure, so I go for safety :p

Comment: Was also typing an answer, you guys are so fast :)

Comment: It will be broadcasted, I think. And it is not sometimes. Broadcasting has rules. Anyways, in this case *safety* might have a price which is less performance :p

Comment: Probably... but isn't broadcasting itself a performance-taking operation?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yeah, maybe. It depends on the implementation.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to always work with all backends? In the documentation of the `Multiply` layer it explicitly says "It takes as input a list of tensors, **all of the same shape**, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape)." while here we are multiplying shapes `(255,255,3)` and `(255,255,1)` (or even `(255,255)`). So, either documentation is incomplete, not mentioning broadcasting, or there are some circumstances when this is not working...

Comment: @DanielMöller You were right, and I was wrong. Sorry! You need to add that third axis. I was mistaking it with the case of multiplying two arrays of shape: `(b1, b2, ..., bM, a1, a2, ..., aN)` and `(a1, a2, ..., aN)` which will be broadcasted.

Comment: @sebrockm, I only use tensorflow. But in a case you test and it doesn't work, you can go for `Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x]*3, axis=-1)(mask)` instead of the reshape.

Comment: I don't know if theano is still like that, but you might need to pass the `output_shape` argument to the lambda layers.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can do this using a `Lambda` layer (as in @DanielMöller's answer you need to add a third axis to the mask):

```py
from keras import backend as K

out = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] * K.expand_dims(x[1], axis=-1))([image, mask])
```